# How to add Background ad on blogger

Tags: background-image, blogger

Is it feasible to do something like that? I would like to add a background clickable image (ad) like this http://goo.gl/xSmwq in my blogger blog?

Can you help me providing the required code?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well there isn't a background clickable image if you see, there is an "transparent image" with the position fixed:

[image]

try to put in your Cascading Style Sheets (CSS):

```
body {
background-image: url("http://banners.dol.gr/opap_skin_kathigitis_tovima.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 40PX;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #000000 !important;
}
.background {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:999;visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:880px;}
.background .first-banner {position:fixed;left:50%;visibility:visible;margin-left:-800px;}
```

and then in your html code:

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="first-banner">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">
      <img width="300" height="880" src="http://static.adman.gr/void.gif" border="0">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps! :)